# Refresh different div after jquery success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an edit button that allows me to update the data from the inputs inside the div below. I'm sending the data using jQuery and then updating my database. I want to be able to update that div that is holding all the updatable inputs on the success of the call. My div is holding information supplied by a different jQuery call.

```
function post() {
    var grade_id = $('#grade_id').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var dealer = $('#dealer').val();
    var length = $('#length').val();
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    $.post (
       'db/ajax/steel.php'
        {editname:name,editdealer:dealer,editlength:length,
        editprice:price,editcomment:comment,editgrade_id:grade_id},
        function(data) {
            $('#popup-background').fadeOut();
            $('#steel-edit-container').fadeOut();
            location.reload();
    });
 }
```

is the java that is making the update call and this works just fine. The information in the div that I just updated does not however update until I refresh the page. I was wondering if I could do it within the success of this call. I have refreshed the page using the location.reolod() function but was wondering if there was a better way. This is the div that is holding the updatable inputs.

```
 <div id="steel-results" class="column-select-container-result">

 </div>
```

Comment: The `reload` demolishes the use of Ajax. Try using the data in your success callback: `$("#theDiv").load(data);`

Comment: Also, please don't refer to your code as java

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function post() {
    var grade_id = $('#grade_id').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var dealer = $('#dealer').val();
    var length = $('#length').val();
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    $.ajax({
    url: 'db/ajax/steel.php' ,
    type: "POST",
    data: "editname=" + name + "&editdealer=" + dealer + "&editlength="+length+"&editprice=" + price + "&editcomment="+comment+"&editGrade="+grade_id,
        dataType : 'json'
    success: function(result){
        $('#popup-background').fadeOut();
            $('#steel-edit-container').fadeOut();
            $('#name').val(result.name);
            $('#dealer').val(result.dealer);
            $('#length').val(result.length);
            $('#price').val(result.price);
            $('#comment').val(result.comment);
            $('#grade_id').val(grade_id);
    }
    });

 }
```

Please pass the values json format in steel.php